# ASP.Net website 'Error BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types' on publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to publish a website (or webapp, not sure how to tell which it is) in Visual Studio 2019, .Net Framework v4.5.1. It builds without a problem but always throws an error when I try to publish:

```
Error BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
```

The error refers to this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="subButton" runat="server" />
```

Which fires this in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
```

This button is already on our live website working fine, and hasn't been changed in years so I don't understand why it is suddenly a problem. All the answers I have seen online suggest adding a WithEvents clause - but there is nowhere to put it because the button is not defined in code.

Can anyone suggest how I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Before you try and publish, you want to ensure that the project builds. (Edit -- my bad and apologies- I see u noted the project builds).

However, if you have just this one error?

You can fix this error one of several ways

comment out the whole stub (don't delete - you need the code inside)

After you comment out the code stub (highlight code stub ctrl-k, ctrl-c)

Then on the page in design mode, just double click on the button.

Flip back to code behind, and you see a new event click, and then you can cut+paste in the orginal code stub, and un-command (highlight code, ctrl-k, ctrl-u)  (of course you can always highlight, and from menu choose commnent/un-comment code).

At that point the error should be gone.

vb is able to wire up a click event two ways.

So, the 2nd way?

Remove from the code stub the "Handles Search.Click", and then in markup, simple type in as a attribute of the button, "onclick=".

WHEN you hit "=" then intel-sense should pop up a choice of events. Like this:

[image]

so, if from the designer, you double click on a button, then you get a event + "with events".

But, you can also type in markup onclick=  (and the instant you hit "=", then you get inteli-sense. And you can even use create new event if you wish).

The result in both case works identical. It just that in the one case, "with events" will automatic wire up the event at the page class level, and thus no "onclick" attribute is required on the button.

Often you see the 2nd format (onclick="some event name") when a button was dropped inside of a repeater, or say gridview. In those cases, you can't double click on the button, since you get the gridview/listview/repeater etc. events. So, to wire up a plane jane button inside of such data controls, you wind up having to specify the onclick event in markup.

So, SINCE the orginal did have "with events"?

Then before you do anything, I would try from the menu a build->rebuild solution first. (In fact, I would open form in design mode, and "dirty" the form (just in markup hit enter). This will force the page class to re-build, and thus your error may well go away. If the build error persists, then try step 1 or 2 above.

I suppose most simple would be to remove "with events" from the code behind, and then simple in markup add a onclick= attribute of that button, and as noted, it should pop up a list of choices - including your click event stub (with "withevents" having been removed by you).

However, you should try and determine if this was a "web site" or a "web site application".

Since this is vb, then if you open as a project, then you get a reference settings page (which is MUCH MUCH MUCH MUCH nicer then the c# one).

This one:

project->"your project name" properies.

You then see this:

[image]

With above, you can "instant" see if any references are missing. But then again, a simple attempt using build project also would tell you if references are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, [Albert D. Kallal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10527/albert-d-kallal). That didn't help but I appreciate the effort, and maybe it can help someone else. I had a click event on the search button like this:

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
```

I noticed that the Id of the button was btnSearch, which was not was being looked for in the Handles clause. I tried changing the Handles clause to match the button but it didn't work. It was only when I changed the Id of the button to just Search that it finally published successfully.

Unfortunately, now i've got the code on the server i've got a different error - but I won't go into that here.